# Spring: re-initialized a bean

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, grpc, spring-webflux

This is my Spring bean in the configuration class that creates a gRPC ManagedChannel:

```
@Configuration
public class CockroachDbConfig {


 @Bean
 public ManagedChannel getManagedChannel() {
    return ManagedChannelBuilder.forTarget(CR_GRPC_SERVER)
        .usePlaintext()
        .build();
   }
 }
```

The controller method is provided below:

```
@RestController
public class DBProxyController {

    @Autowired
    private DBProxyService dbProxyService;


    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.POST,
        consumes = APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,
        produces = APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE
    )
    @SuppressWarnings("BlockingMethodInNonBlockingContext")
    public Mono<Void> handleRequest(@RequestBody String requestBody, ServerHttpResponse serverHttpResponse, ServerHttpRequest request)  {


        org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders headers = request.getHeaders();

        Map<String, String> responseMap = dbProxyService.processRequest(requestBody, headers);

        String response = responseMap.get(X_AMZN_RESPONSE);

        if (response.equalsIgnoreCase("{}")) {
            LOGGER.info("We are ot able to sucessfully process the request and reutning an empty response");
        }

        return serverHttpResponse.writeWith(strToDataBuffer(response));
    }
}
```

The service class is:

```
@Service
public class DBProxyService {


    public Map<String, String> processRequest(final String requestBody, final org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders headers)  {


        ManagedChannel customManagedChannel = (new CockroachDbConfig()).getManagedChannel();

        switch (action) {

            case GETITEM:
            {

                // some code
                ProtoService.shutdownManagedChannel(customManagedChannel);
            }
            case PUTITEM:
            {
                // some code
                ProtoService.shutdownManagedChannel(customManagedChannel);
            }
            
        }

    }

}
```

For each request, I create a new `ManagedChannel` in the service method `processRequest` and shut it down using the method called `shutdownManagedChannel`.

Earlier, I try to use the `@Autowired` for the managed channel as below:

```
@Service
public class DBProxyService {


    @Autowired 
    private ManagedChannel customManagedChannel;

    public Map<String, String> processRequest(final String requestBody, final org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders headers)  {



        switch (action) {

            case GETITEM:
            {

                // some code
                ProtoService.shutdownManagedChannel(customManagedChannel);
            }
            case PUTITEM:
            {
                // some code
                ProtoService.shutdownManagedChannel(customManagedChannel);
            }
            
        }

    }

}
```

This was not successful as I shut down the channel after the completion of each request and I guess need to figure out a way to re-initialize the bean for each call.

So, how to I re-initialize the `ManagedChannel` for each request when the app is running?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you really need to re-create this bean for each request? You could make the bean `@RequestScoped` so that each request has its own instance.

Comment: I think there is no need for me to create a new instance for each request. Would you please write to me how can I use the `@ RequestScoped` for this bean?

Comment: If that isn't needed why are you shutting it down on each request?

Comment: @M.Deinum this creates a gRPC channel with resources and it's better to shut down when the call is ended.

Comment: Then don't make it a bean but create one and dispose it. Making this a bean doesn't add anything then.

Comment: This is for the testing purpose as that test will have a different way to create the managed channel. For now, I just committed the shutdown method in the app code, and in the test write a method that creates the managed channel. This is not the most elegant way but works fine for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution, not relying too much on the framework would be to inject a bean of type `Supplier<ManagedChannel>` (or any other functional interface type that works for your use case).

```java
@Bean
public Suuplier<ManagedChannel> getManagedChannel() {
  return () -> ManagedChannelBuilder.forTarget(CR_GRPC_SERVER)
      .usePlaintext()
      .build();
}
```

And then use the `get` method to re-instantiate a new channel whenever you need it.

Otherwise, you could work with the scope `Prototype` that recreates the bean in some circumstances instead of treating it as a singleton ([documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#beans-factory-scopes-prototype)). Be aware that injecting prototype beans in singleton beans require you to do some configuration gymnastic, as stated in the point [1.5.3 of the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#beans-factory-scopes-sing-prot-interaction).

Comment: this is a good answer, I would more appreciate it if you can write the use-case for the prototype bean for me as well.

Comment: There are multiple solutions, each with its own pros and cons. Without more context, I can't really do it. This [article](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-inject-prototype-bean-into-singleton) summarize it pretty well. Take your pick. As for my preference, I always go for the `Supplier` approach because it is the one with less overhead and the most simple to understand (and to interface in unit testing as well).

Comment: I can confirm that the above code works. Just tested and I think my intention is fulfilled.